# Theorem proving in Lean, for areas that aren't quite ready for it

Tags: proof-assistants, formalization

While taking a break from being stuck, I have found myself addicted to [playing with the Lean Theorem Prover.](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Ebuzzard/xena/natural_number_game/) (Beware, if you visit this link might you might find yourself hooked...)

Playing with this made me dream of gamifying my own research problems in Lean. I'm an operator algebraist, though, and even thinking about basic examples in Banach Algebra theory via holomorphic functional calculus would require things like the Cauchy Integral Theorem, for example...among many other things. I mention this because the Cauchy Integral Theorem and basic Complex Analysis is absent from mathlib.

I wonder if "sorry" and such can be used to build things from the top down in a way that would allow one's current work to be eventually retrofit to mathlib (with effort), and at least check one's theorems modulo certain assumptions. Is anyone trying to do such a thing, or is it going to be necessary to focus on building up and porting mathlib sufficiently for people like me to "plug in"?

Thanks, in advance for any tips and best practices you might share!

(I know I could have asked this on the Zulip chat for Lean, but I figured I'm not the only one with this problem over here at MO...)

Comment: Apparently there will soon be a dedicated stackexchange for formal theorem provers

Comment: That will be great!

Comment: See https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants

Comment: @SamHopkins, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/411897/theorem-proving-in-lean-for-areas-that-arent-quite-ready-for-it#comment1055465_411897), there already is (depending on what the definition of 'is' is):  https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/126242/proof-assistants.  (Oops, beaten by 18 seconds!)

Comment: To clarify, though, I think MO is still the right place for this, because I want to know about best practices for importing and checking my own mathematics...perhaps by black boxing things that Lean's mathlib isn't yet up to speed with.

Comment: This question, I mean...

Comment: There is a project called Formal Abstracts (https://formalabstracts.github.io/, https://github.com/formalabstracts) which was supposed to develop standards for formalising definitions and statements from the literature without proofs.  I think that that would be very valuable, but unfortunately it seems that the project has stalled, with no visible activity since 2019.

Comment: I know Kevin Buzzard had a student who worked out a statement of the BSD conjecture with "sorry"s for certain proofs that are needed to justify the statement of the theorem (the most difficult of which being the analytic continuation of $L$-functions of elliptic curves). So this is considered at least sometimes a reasonable thing to work on by people in that space.